# How to get count of subscribers for each member?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get a count of subscribers for each member using sequalize query but didn't get an accurate response.
Error: **Something went wrong, s.replace is not a function**

> Code :

```
exports.getSingleMember = async (req, res, next) => {

   try{
      let member =  await db.Member.scope('removePassword').findOne({
         where:{username: req.params.uname},
         include:[
            {model: db.Gallery, attributes:['id','member_img']},
            {model: db.Review, attributes:['id','review']},
            {model: db.Country, required: true, attributes:['id','name']},
            {model: db.City, attributes:['id','name']},
            {model: db.Subscribe, attributes:['id',[[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col('id')), 'total']] ]},
         ]
      });
      if(member != null) {

         return responses.success(res, data = member);
 

      } else {

         return responses.notFound(res, errors = true, msg = "Member is not found.");

      }
   } catch (e) {
      return responses.internalError(res, `Something went wrong, ${e.message}`);
   }
}
```